# Jmeter functions doesn't work on remote (distribute) server

Tags: jmeter, load, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

my problem is:

1. I have simple script with Jmeter variables in "TestPlan" section:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpmaC.png)

2. when I run this script localy in my client macine function ${__TestPlanName} works correctly and returns value "MyTestPlan.jmx"
3. when I run this script in remote server (no matter use GUI mode or non GUI mode!) function ${__TestPlanName} doesn't return name of script but keeps value "${__TestPlanName}"

I've repeated with behavior with different Jmeter functions (such as ${__time(...)} or ${__P(nameProperty, defaultProperty)}) but every time I've got the same results:

- for function __time I've got value "${__time(...)"
- for function __P I've got value "${__P(nameProperty, defaultProperty)}"

I also tried to use non GUI mode with option "-G" for Global properties but it does't work correct too! But it works with "-J" options in local machine!

In my opinion the problem is that Jmeter fuctions doen't evaluating on remote (distribute) server.

Could you help me please to resolve this problem!
I need to get variable exactly in the TestPlan section!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue.

[image]

1. Check [`jmeter-server.log` file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) on the slave side for any suspicious entries
2. Check the presence of [`ApacheJMeter_functions.jar` library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_functions) under "lib/ext" folder on the slave machine. If it's not there either download it from Maven Central using the above link or better [reinstall JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-installation-test-plans) as there could be other problems. You should also be able to copy full JMeter installation from master to slave, in this case you won't have to worry about missing .jars or [plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) or CSV files or whatever.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've tried your code and it realy works, but I tried to use my Jmeter variable "pn" in Listener (I use Plugin BackendListener to save my results to ClickHouse DataBase). And when I tried to save with variable to DB (as profile name)- it saves like "${__TestPLanName}". It seems like variable "pn" doesn't evaluate on Listeners level...